# ReactJS: A non-serializable value was detected in an action

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting and try my application and I receive this error when I try to make an api call:

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path:
> `payload`.

This is my store:

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: {
      ignoredActions: ['payload.config', 'payload.request', 'error', 'meta.arg'],
    }
  }).concat(errorMiddleware, notificationMiddleware, loadingBarMiddleware(), loggerMiddleware),
});

const getStore = () => store;

export type IRootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<IRootState> = useSelector;
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>();
export type AppThunk<ReturnType = void> = ThunkAction<ReturnType, IRootState, unknown, AnyAction>;

export default getStore;
```

My reducer:

```
export const apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/';

export const getEntities: ICrudGetAllAction<IService> = (page, size, sort) => {
    const requestUrl = `${apiUrl}${sort ? `?page=${page}&size=${size}&sort=${sort}` : ''}`;
    return {
        type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_SERVICE_LIST,
        payload: axios.get<IProMappaServizi>(`${requestUrl}${sort ? '&' : '?'}cacheBuster=${new Date().getTime()}`),
    };
};
```

And the page where I make the api call is:

```
export const ServiceList = (props: IService) => {

useEffect(() => {
        props.getEntities();
    }, [])
return (
        <div>
           //....
        </div>
    )
}
const mapStateToProps = //....

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getEntities
};

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type DispatchProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ServiceList )
```

How can I fix this error? is a store problem?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

redux toolkit checks for serialized data with a default middleware.

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware

you could disable this check with:

```
const store = configureStore({
reducer: rootReducer,
middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
getDefaultMiddleware({
  thunk: {
    extraArgument: myCustomApiService,
  },
  serializableCheck: false,
}),
})
```

But thats not recommended.

Comment: disabling it is not really fixing the issue. any idea whats causing it?
mine points me to 
https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string-or-at-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants